# Feature set buffer script is not working in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, buffer, arcgis-pro, feature-set

I've created a script that takes in a user selected point through a FeatureSet parameter then creates a buffer of that point. It worked fine in ArcMap but now our work is migrating everything to ArcGIS Pro. I made the necessary changes with arcpy.mp instead of arcpy.mapping, etc. but am now getting an rutime error message when I try and add my buffer layer. The script is also created using a toolbox that I cam accessing in ArcGIS Pro.

This is my code:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:/GIS/Data/Sinks.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False
inPts = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #Empty featureSet that the user clicks 
anywhere on the map to create, the schema is set as an x/y point previously 
created
distance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(inPts, "sourcePt_1")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("sourcePt_1", "point1_lyr")

p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps("Layers")[0]

#automatically clearing out previous buffer
if arcpy.Exists("Sink_Search_Radius"):
    arcpy.Delete_management("Sink_Search_Radius")
else:
    pass
arcpy.AddMessage("Removing previous buffers.")
for lyr in m.listLayers():
    if lyr.name == "Sink_Search_Radius":
        m.removeLayer(lyr)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Sink selection buffer removed.")
else:
    pass

if arcpy.Exists("E:/GIS/Data/Sources.gdb/Source_Search_Radius"):    
   arcpy.Delete_management("E:/Data//Sources.gdb/Source_Search_Radius")
else:
    pass

for lyr in m.listLayers():
    if lyr.name == "Source_Search_Radius":
        m.removeLayer(lyr)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Source selection buffer removed.")
    else:
        pass

for lyr in m.listLayers():
    if lyr.name == "nPoint":
        m.removeLayer(lyr)         
        arcpy.AddMessage("Point removed.")
    else:
        pass

 #Buffering point
 arcpy.AddMessage("Drawing a search radius around your point.")
 arcpy.Buffer_analysis("point1_lyr", "Sink_Search_Radius", distance)
 Bufflyr = ("E:/GIS/Data/Sinks.gdb/Sink_Search_Radius")
 m.addDataFromPath(Bufflyr) #where I get my errror
 arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management("Sink_Search_Radius", 
 "E:/GIS/Data/Sinks/BuffFc.lyr")
 arcpy.AddMessage("Beginning to perform your selection.")
```

Comment: Try adding an r before your path, e.g. `Bufflyr = (r"E:/GIS/Data/Sinks.gdb/Sink_Search_Radius")`

Comment: @smiller still did not work. This is the error that I keep getting: File "E:\GIS\Data\ArcGISPro_Sinks\CheckBox_Script_Pro.py", line 64, in <module>
    m.addDataFromPath(Bufflyr)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\_mp.py", line 1248, in addDataFromPath
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.addDataFromPath(*gp_fixargs((data_path,), True)))
RuntimeError
 Failed to execute (ViewSinksAroundAnySource).